# React Native: How to Determine if Device is iPhone or iPad

Tags: react-native

I know with React Native that we have the ability to determine whether iOS or Android is being run using the `Platform` module, but how can we determine what device is being used on iOS?

Answer (score 50):

As of 9.02.2018 there is also

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
Platform.isPad // boolean
```

Mind that (as of now) it has no android counterpart.

- IOS https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Utilities/Platform.ios.js#L23
- Android https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Utilities/Platform.android.js (no isPad!)

Comment: undefined for react native 0.57

Comment: Platform.OS === 'ios'

Comment: it's Perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 25):

Simplest approach will be using the aspect ratio. The code will be:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window'); 
const aspectRatio = height/width;

if(aspectRatio>1.6) {

   // Code for Iphone

}
else {

   // Code for Ipad

}
```

Aspect ratio of iPad is 4:3 (1.334) and aspect ratio of iPhone is 16:9 (1.778)

Make sure to check if you are on an iOS device using `Platform.OS === 'ios'` method before applying the above logic.

Comment: This could also work on Android to detect a tablet no?

Comment: This will work with android but not all Android tablets have the same aspect ratio.

Comment: Please take landscape portrait positions in account! The code above will turn your iPhone in an iPad when turning it 90 degrees:-).

Answer (score 15):

if using TypeScript, there is a type in react-native called `PlatformIOSStatic`, you need to force-cast `Platform` to `PlatformIOSStatic`.

```js
import { Platform, PlatformIOSStatic } from 'react-native'

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  const platformIOS = Platform as PlatformIOSStatic
  console.log(platformIOS.isPad)
  console.log(platformIOS.isTVOS)
}
```

The interface design here is pretty bad, hope RN team would improve it.

Comment: isPad??? Wow. I totally missed that.

Comment: You don't need to do any casting, it's a discriminated union type. `Platform.OS === "ios" && Platform.isPad` works just fine

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for a way to do that without including 3rd party libraries (like react-native-device-info) you can also do:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { PlatformConstants } = NativeModules;
const deviceType = PlatformConstants.interfaceIdiom;
```

`deviceType` can take the values: `phone`, `pad`, `tv`, `carplay` and `unknown`.

Comment: this solution return me "undefined".

Answer (score 7):

You can roughly determine what iOS device is being used without any external dependencies... First query `Platform.OS` then the [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) module allows you to query the device for screen dimensions which can be translated to devices: http://iosres.com/

Comment: I liked the "without any external dependencies", people let their code get so dependent on unnecessary libs my head hurts sometimes.

+1

Answer (score 6):

I used isTablet() to detect ipad with iphone
https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info

```
import { isTablet } from 'react-native-device-info';
if (isTablet()) {
// try something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to get that information from the module `react-native-device-info`

https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info

Comment: I certainly prefer this approach, as assuming Apple will never produce a device with a different aspect ratio is a bit risky, and this module does actually relate to models. Sadly the emulator returns "Simulator" which is a bit awkward for testing.

Answer (score 4):

Both will return true in iPad if you have set iPad configuration in the target of the project in code in general otherwise it will return flase.

```
import { isTablet } from 'react-native-device-info';
isTablet()
```

OR

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
Platform.isPad // boolean
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$ `npm install react-native-device-detection --save`

$ `react-native link`

---

```
if(Device.isIos) {

}

if(Device.isTablet) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48709199/2400373

My solution final is this:

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";

Dispositivo() {
    if (Platform.isPad == true) {
      return(
       <Text>test</Text>
      )
    }
```

Then I call this function:

```
{this.Dispositivo()}
```

Answer (score -2):

A good solution by @Maxwelll. 
A more accurate approach would be to measure the screen ratio.
All iPhones are 16:9, all iPads are 3:4.

Comment: Not all the iPhones are 16:9 and not all iPads are 3:4, consider this link: https://28b.co.uk/ios-device-dimensions-reference-table/