# Dimensions.get('screen').width returns wrong width in iPad simulator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

`Dimensions.get('screen').width` is returning a width of `320` for my `iPad simulator`.

> No matter which iPad device I try to use in the simulator, it returns
>   a 320 x 480 screen and window resolution

.

Am I doing something wrong here or does this just not work right in the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dani Akash I think I found a solution that will work for what I'm trying to do here. [React Native: How to Determine if Device is iPhone or iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249604/react-native-how-to-determine-if-device-is-iphone-or-ipad)

The suggestion was to use the aspect ratio to determine if it's a tablet or not.

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window'); 
const aspectRatio = height/width;

if(aspectRatio>1.6) {

   // Code for Iphone

}
else {

   // Code for Ipad

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the unit of react-native width & height is **density-independent pixels**, not normal pixels.

Why use [**density-independent pixels**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html#fixed-dimensions)?

There are too many dimensions with smartphone devices. Components should looks the same regardless of screen dimensions.

> Setting dimensions this way is common for components that should
>   always render at exactly the same size, regardless of screen
>   dimensions.

For most cases you can just use [Layout with Flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make my layout responsive depending on if the user is using an iPhone or an iPad. Simply just changing the flex-direction from column to row depending on the device so it fits better. Wouldn't this be the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is after the fact, but you can also use [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info), which has a method isTablet().  I'm not sure what version of RN you are using, but Dimensions.get('window') should work fine, I think the issue might have been that you were using 'screen' instead of 'window'.

Comment: i test my code on ipad device, i get the 320 x 480 by using `Dimensions.get("window")` ( same results with screen btw )