# How to set force device orientation based on device type in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I've a React Native app, for some screens in that app, I need to set landscape view for tablet and for other portrait in mobile.

Although my question is same as below question, the only difference being mine is a React native, so I'll need solution for both Android and iOS

[Android : How set force device orientation by device type (tablet, phone)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176609/android-how-set-force-device-orientation-by-device-type-tablet-phone)

Answer (score 0):

From many answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249604/react-native-how-to-determine-if-device-is-iphone-or-ipad) question, what we get is that to identify whether the device is a tablet or a phone, you can use either [this](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#istablet) package's `isTablet()` or [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect) package's `isMobile` and `isTablet`.

After identifying, next from [the resource](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/?redirected) provided by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46671734/8244632) question's answer, you can lock or unlock the device's orientation.

The expo documentation link provided above as the resource will help you lock the orientation no matter what the platform or OS is.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But actually I'm not using Expo. By any chance do you've any other solution you can help me with? :)